# Bootstrap one height to columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use this (jsfiddle.net/wwWVd/) markup to make sidebars. (Make viewport width more, to see the problem or open this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/wwWVd/show/).

As you can see, block height is different. Can I make it one height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to use CSS flexbox..

```
.flex, .flex > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 0 auto;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/127641

Answer (score 0):

Floated elements do not acquire their parent's or siblings' height.

If you want same heights on elements, either use table or set columns to absolute position, then on columns set `height 100%; top:0; bottom:0;` to get height of their parent.